# returning a little square :s

Tags: java, arrays

Hey fellow stack overflowerssss,

I have written;

```
public class testing
{
    public String subString(int start, int end) 
    {   
        char[]content = new char[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        String output ="";
        for (int i = 0; i < content.length;i++)
        {
            if (content[i] >= start && content[i] < end)
            {
                output = output + content[i];
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        testing test1 = new testing();

        System.out.println( test1.subString(1,2));
    }

}
```

**Returns**:

```
[]
```

It works in a way no matter how I try and split it will return the correct number of little square. I'm guessing its because I am trying to put an array element in a string ?

The return needs to be string also.

Can anyone help me out.

P.S I know there is a function for this :)

Comment: What do you mean by `little squares`.. ?

Comment: No i mean little squares, e.g as a result I will get two little square to represent 2 nummbers

Comment: The char '1' is not the same thing as a int 1, therefore your if condition won't return true

Comment: @MadProgrammer Except he was using `1`, not `'1'`, so the (unprintable) characters really were getting appended. He just wasn't seeing them on the screen.

Comment: @chrylis running in the same direction ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's printing exactly what you told it to: open bracket, [`SOH`, `STX`](http://www.ascii-code.com/), close bracket. If you're wanting it to print `[12]`, your `content` should be `{'0','1','2'...}`, and your `if` condition should be `i >= start && i < end`.

Comment: @jlordo Indeed. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

The *little squares* are ASCII characters with codes from 0 to 9. I think you meant to declare an `int[]` array, and not a `char[]` array.

Do this:

```
char[] array = new char[] {'1', '2', '3', '4'};
```

or

```
int[] array = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

You got the idea.

It's a programmer flaw, not a program bug.

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to print char that its value is 1 ( >=1 and < 2). look at this ascii table to understand what are you writing:

[image]

i believe you wanted to do:

```
char[]content = new char[]{'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
```

and so your code is:

```
public class testing
{
    public String subString(int start, int end) 
    {   
    char[]content = new char[]{'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
        String output ="";
        for (int i = 0; i < content.length;i++)
        {
            if (content[i] >= start && content[i] < end)
            {
                output = output + content[i];
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        testing test1 = new testing();

        System.out.println( test1.subString(1,2));
    }

}
```

and the return value is:

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have as I understand it two different problems here, the first is with your array of characters.
You have char[]content = new char[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; which indicates the ascII values 0-9 which is probably; not what you are looking for, specifically char[]content = new char[]{'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'}; is what you want

Secondly as the if statement that checks if you are in the right range is simply incorrect, you should be checking the index is in the correct range not the value: if (i >= start && i < end)

These issues will make your algorithm work; however there are much better solutions to this general problem; perhaps you think about whether you really need to go through the entire contents of the array?

Answer (score 0):

The initialization of content might not do what you think.

```
char[]content = new char[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

If the output you want is numbers (and not strange ascii chars), then you have to initialize the array characters as characters, i.e put them with apostrophes as this:

```
char[]content = new char[]{'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
```

Your code does not yield errors because the internal representation of characters are numbers.